# After rolling the die 5 times what is the probability that P has passed the point (2, 0)?

Tags: probability, statistics

A point P moves on the coordinate plane. After rolling 1 die,

- if the result is 1, 2, or 3: P moves along vector (1, 0)
- if the result is 4: P moves along vector (0, 1)
- if the result is 5 or 6: P moves along vector (1, -1).

P moving along vector (a, b) means that P leaves the prior point M (s, t) for point N (s+a, t+b)
along with line MN. At first, point P is placed at (0, 0).

I think that the probability that P is at (2,0) is 2 times (1,0), therefore (1/2)^2 = 1/4
I am not sure what the probability would be for the P to pass that point?

Comment: It can also go $(1,0)+(0,1)+(1,-1)$ and so on

Comment: You must account for all the possible scenarios that the path can go through $(2,0)$ in 5 moves. Doodling can help.

Comment: Let $(X, Y, Z)$ be the number of moves along the vector $(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1)$ respectively. To reach the point $(2, 0)$ in $5$ moves, we require $X + Z = 2$, $Y - Z = 0$, $X + Y + Z = 5$ which has no solution

Comment: 2X+Y increases at each step so, as BGM says, you won't be exactly there after five step; but you may have already passed through it.